# Unable to connect with Loki. Please check the server logs for more details

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

It's my first time to use loki, when I configured the loki as datasource of Grafana,It signed:

```
Unable to connect with Loki. Please check the server logs for more details.
```

I just follow the official documentation to run Grafana and promail and loki containers, here is the situation of docker containers:
[image]

and I have tried to add "http://localhost:3100", "http://localhost:3101", "http://localhost:3102" as the loki url.But all of these failed with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

The correct url should be

```
host.docker.internal:3100
```

Answer (score 0):

it is a version problem, the grafana version should be compatible with loki's version, try downgrading to 2.6.* and try again

Answer (score 0):

update version:
loki:
image:
tag: 2.9.4